# @font-face with rails 4

Tags: sass, ruby-on-rails-4, font-face

I'm using Rails 4 with Sass, and I'd like to use a custom font.

How do I use @font-face with Sass if the asset pipeline in Rails 4 is no longer utilized?  I can't find anything online about how to do this.

Also, most of what I do find refers to "config.rb," but I only have "config.RU"  Is there a difference?

(I'm newish to Rails so please try to be unambiguous/don't refer to things that have antecedents somebody newish to Rails wouldn't recognize)

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Are the pages that reference a config.rb using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) by chance?

Comment: asset-path("filepath/fonts.woff",style) isnt worked?

Comment: @cimmanon: i couldn't tell you.  does Compass change this extension to .rb?

Comment: @Chandrakant: where do would I put that snippet of code you shared?

Comment: is ther asset pipline used? if yes, then put it into sass file itself, I'll tell you how..or else tell me- how do you insert images in sass- i.e with asset path or without asset path

Comment: I guess I don't really understand clearly what the asset pipeline is.  I've tried certain documentation that I find online but to no avail.  Moreover, I can't find a definition of the asset pipeline or how to use it vis-a-vis Ruby syntax, and desired effect, that doesn't reference something else.  I really just need a primitive definition of the asset pipeline, where it lives, how I add to it, with what syntax, and how I invoke it, for example, in order to get a font in my SASS file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you do not have assets pipeline? If so, you can serve your fonts via "public" folder.

1. Create a directory in public: "public\fonts"
2. Copy your fonts there
3. In your css, declare the font and its location:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'robotolight';
       src: url('/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.eot');
       src: url('/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.svg#robotolight') format('svg');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
   }
   ```

Of course if you are organizing different fonts in different folders, you will need to indicate them as well, eg:

```
url('/fonts/roboto-light/Roboto-Light-webfont.eot');
```

Hope it helps.